Empty Devicelist from FritzBox
I'm currently trying to retrieve all devices from my home network into my C# code. I found the opportunity to use the Fritzbox API. I can easily login and obtain the SID for further requests, but when I call the getdevicelistinfos method, it just returns:
<devicelist version="1" fwversion="7.57"/>.
The URL I request is: http://fritz.box/webservices/homeautoswitch.lua?0=0&sid=secret&switchcmd=getdevicelistinfos
Maybe this endpoint doesn't return all devices, but that's what I understood.
Tried to modify the request URL.
Code looks like this:
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {
     try
     {
         var sessionId = await GetSessionId();
         var devices = await GetDeviceInfo(sessionId, "");
        
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
     }
 }
 private static async Task<string> GetSessionId()
 {
     using (var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(FritzBoxUrl)})
     {
         var response = await client.GetStringAsync("/login_sid.lua");
         var xml = XDocument.Parse(response);
         var sid = xml.Root.Element("SID").Value;
         if (sid != "0000000000000000")
         {
             return sid;
         }

         var challenge = xml.Root.Element("Challenge").Value;
         fritzUserName = xml.Root.Element("Users")?.Element("User").Value;
         var responseHash = CalculateMD5(challenge + "-" + Password);
         var content = new StringContent($"response={challenge}-{responseHash}&username={fritzUserName}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

         var loginResponse = await client.PostAsync("/login_sid.lua", content);
         var loginResponseContent = await loginResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         var loginXml = XDocument.Parse(loginResponseContent);
         var loginSid = loginXml.Root.Element("SID").Value;


         if (loginSid == "0000000000000000")
         {
             throw new Exception();
         }

         return loginSid;
     }
 }


private static async Task<string> ExecuteCommand(string sid, string command, string ain, string path)
{
    path += "/webservices/homeautoswitch.lua?0=0";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sid))
        path += "&sid=" + sid;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(command))
        path += "&switchcmd=" + command;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ain))
        path += "&ain" + ain;
    return await HttpRequest(path, new HttpRequestMessage(), "");
}
public static async Task<string> HttpRequest(string path, HttpRequestMessage req, string options)
{
    req.RequestUri = new Uri(FritzBoxUrl + path);
    var client = new HttpClient();
    
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(req);
    string body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode || response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect || body.Contains("action=.?login.lua"))
    {
        throw new HttpRequestException($"HTTP request failed: {response.StatusCode}");
    }

    return body.Trim();
}

private static async Task<string> GetDeviceInfo(string sessionId,string options) => await ExecuteCommand(sessionId, "getdevicelistinfos",null,options);


Please include the [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.  We can't help you debug code we cannot see.

Check the ARP table for the router and MAC address table for the bridge, but remember on-network communication does not involve the router, only the bridge.

Edited question with code

why 0=0?  Try: http://fritz.box/webservices/homeautoswitch.lua?sid=83hre38hr833hr38&switchcmd=getdevicelistinfos
